# Is there a readymade decorator available to cache the function return value based on parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, caching

C# Win Forms Application, requires caching of function's return values, that should be based on the parameters so if function's parameters changes while calling the function it must call again, but for same parameters it should return the value directly from cache, is there any existing C# facility available or any rapid easy technique or link would appreciate.

Answer (score 4):

This technique is called **memoization**. This post from [Bart de Smet's blog](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart) should get you started:

- [Memoization for dummies](http://bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2008/10/21/memoization-for-dummies.aspx)